# second derivative of the logarithmic student t-distribution

Tags: statistics

I would like to determine the second derivative of the log t-distribution. 
Results are given in this paper http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/drew.creal/research/papers/crealKoopmanLucas2012_univariateVolatility.pdf at page 4, chapter 2.2.
I got the first derivative, but not the second one. It would be really nice, if someone could help me with that.

Thanks in advance!
Julia

Comment: If you have the first derivative, can you post it ? I could try.

Comment: thanks, it is (v+1)/2 (1+y^2/((v-2)sigma^2))^(-1) y^2/((v-2)sigma^4)-1/2sigma^2

Comment: it is the same as in the paper (maybe it's better to read it there). I need the second derivative for the inverse Fisher information matrix.